# Representation of fundamental forms of surfaces in five-dimensional Euclidean space and verification of embeddings

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm looking for advice on the **representation of the fundamental forms of surfaces in higher dimensional Euclidean space** and **verification of the embeddings**.

I have only studied differential geometry in **3D Euclidean space** so far, and **have not learned enough about manifolds**, but would like to study the properties of surfaces in 5D Euclidean space.
Is there a representation **close to the one in 3D Euclidean space** that would be beneficial to my understanding? Or any course/book you can suggest for me to study.

Comment: What's so special about 5D? Once you leave 3D, things get much more complicated. The geometry of surfaces in 3D is largely dependent on understanding the second fundamental form. When you get to larger dimensions, the second fundamental form is vector-bundle valued, and things are far less well understood. You now need to study linear systems of quadratic forms, not a single quadratic form, at each point.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your reply.
I've actually been studying Hilbert's theorem and Rozendorn's conclusion recently, respectively:

Hilbert:There exists no C2 complete connected surface in 3D Euclidean space making its Gaussian curvature a negative constant;
Rozendorn:There exists a smooth isometric immersion of a hyperbolic plane into a five-dimensional Euclidean space.[See Prop. 2.2.5 in Han, Qing; Hong, Jia-Xing, Isometric embedding of Riemannian manifolds in Euclidean spaces, Mathematical Surveys and Monographs 130.]

Comment: The isometric embedding problem is a matter of PDEs and has nothing to do with the extrinsic geometry of the embedding. It is about the first fundamental form only. Of course, the Gauss equations will relate the intrinsic Gaussian curvature and the ambient curvature, and that will presumably be part of the integrability conditions.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for your guidance.